# How to pass several variables to the node of the linked list in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a function that adds data as a node to the front of the linked list, but I am not sure how to do similarly with 10 items for example

```
class Courses:: addCoursesdata(const int& elem) {
    CourseNode *tmp = this->head;
    this->head = new CourseNode(elem);
    this->head->next = tmp;

}
```

What if I have multiple elements to the addition off elem variable? How to do it without writing massive code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to add 10 separate nodes to the linked list? You'd either call this function 10 times or write a function that calls this 10 times (or n times). You can even keep the same function name but give it a different signature like `addCourseData(const std::vector<int>& elems)` or whatever container you're looking to use.

Comment: Why do you want to pass them all at once? Can you give us an example of how you want to use that please?

Comment: I have data for each student with their id, username, name, email, and i should build students as a  linked list, and i am not sure how to make 1 node tto have 1 student with its properties(email, name)

Comment: I'd be tempted to `return this` so that you can chain these calls e.g. `mylist.addCoursesdata(c1).addCoursesdata(c2)`. I'd also consider renaming the method as it's not clear whether `addX()` appends to a list or prepends (as much as I dislike that word).

Comment: @YernarMukayev So you need something like `class Courses:: addCoursesdata(const Student& elem) {` and of course chnge the `CourseNode` to keep `Student` as value. Or do you ask how to initialize a `Strudent` instance with this data at hand?

Comment: Are you asking how to add multiple students to the list or how to add a single student based on multiple pieces of information? Adding an example to your question might help clarify what you are asking. (I don't necessarily mean example code. You could describe the situation and the desired result in words.)

Comment: Sorry that I did not clarify it, but what if i have 2 classes(students and cources)- and they represented as linked lists, and i am not sure how to store data for courses and students to two linked list correctly, separately. What will be the right approach to create a linked list for cources with bunch of characteristics?similar with students.. Genereally i just not sure how to store data to linked list for 2 classes with number of variables

Comment: @YernarMukayev You are asking about templates? How to reuse the same linked list code for different kinds of data? The answer would be to template your linked list code.

Comment: The linked list element does not need to be an `int` or a `double` or a `const char*`. It can be an entire `class` or `struct`. The preferred way to do this in C++ is to separate your *container* code from your *element* code, and you do that with templates. That way your container can work with any kind of element. Here, your linked list is a container. It should be able to hold anything.

Comment: @JohnFilleau He is probably a beginner

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add ALL the information necessary for answering, with your current question the answer is that there is no way, but if you add information we can tell you a better way of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Aryan yeah sure, the misunderstanding seems to be though that the linked list can only hold `int`s. @OP, correct me if I'm wrong. If OP wants a linked list that can hold `Student` objects, then they just replace `int` with `Student` everywhere if they don't want to use templates.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Yeah exactly!  Also why OP isn't using `std::list` and why list and not a simple array or a vector. One who wants to answer the question doesn't need to find all the necessary information in the comment section but it should be included in the question body itself

Comment: On a side note, your `student` class and your `List` should be different and a list object should be the member attribute of your student class. All the insert/remove/pop functions should be a part of your `List` class

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add all items at once.

This means that you need to iterate through the container and call the `insert()` function for every element.

```
for(auto const elem:values)
{
    my_list.insert(elem);
}
```

Unless you have a really good reason not to use the in-built `std::list`, use it.

Also if your sole purpose is to simply keep a record of all the student objects, consider using `std::vector<student_class>` or an array as linked-lists have a lot of [**overhead**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_(computing)#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20overhead%20is,to%20perform%20a%20specific%20task.&text=Examples%20of%20computing%20overhead%20may,data%20transfer%2C%20and%20data%20structures.)